# SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow on the specific folder of library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

> I want to create the Designer workflow which should work on the
>   specific folder only. Lets say I have xyz library and it has the Test
>   folder, so now when the document/file is added in this folder then 
>   mail should hit to the Admin/Creator of this folder. I did not get any
>   such method till now in designer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Workflow could not be associated with folder, but you could create a List Workflow and specify the following condition to verify if item is located under a folder named `Test`:

`CurrentItem:Path` `ends with` `Test`

[image]